# Using subtraction from integers to make a linear line gradient

Tags: c++, colors, line, linear-gradients

I've been hacking away at this code trying to get this Parametric Line to make a gradient from Magenta to Cyan based upon the length of the line (so it doesn't get cut off by a short line, or happen too soon on a longer line) I'm trying to figure out the formula to find what I'd be subtracting, but I can't seem to figure it out, any ideas?

```
void ParametricLine(unsigned int _X1, unsigned int _Y1,
                unsigned int _X2, unsigned int _Y2)
{

    unsigned int lengthX;
    unsigned int lengthY;

    lengthX = abs((int)_X2 - (int)_X1);
    lengthY = abs((int)_Y2 - (int)_Y1);

    int longest;
    if (lengthX > lengthY)
    {
        longest = lengthX;
    }
    else
    {
        longest = lengthY;
    }

    unsigned int color = 16711935; //magenta is green 0, others 255
    unsigned int magenta = 16711935; //magenta is green 0, others 255

    unsigned int cyan = 65535;  //cyan is red = 0, G & B are 255
    //all 255 = 16777215

    unsigned int colorsubtract = (magenta - cyan)/longest;

    //MAGENTA: R: 255, G: 0,   B: 255
    //CYAN:    R:0,    G: 255, B: 255

    for (int i = 0; i < longest; i++)
    {
        float Ratio = (float)i / longest;

        unsigned int CurrY = LERP(_Y1, _Y2, Ratio);
        unsigned int CurrX = LERP(_X1, _X2, Ratio);
        /*color = LERP(16711935, 65535, longest/65535);*/
        if (color > cyan)
            color = color - colorsubtract;
        else if (color < cyan)
            color = cyan;

        //interpolate from magenta to cyan
        raster[Position(CurrX, floor(CurrY + 0.5))] = color;
    }
    raster[Position(_X1, _Y1)] = 16777215;
    raster[Position(_X2, _Y2)] = 16777215;
}
```

edit: here's the Lerp function for those asking-

```
unsigned int LERP(unsigned int _startval, unsigned int _endval, float _ratio){
return (((int)_endval - (int)_startval) * _ratio + (int)_startval);}
```

Comment: What is LERP() function/macro? Your code is not complete. How are we supposed to know what your code does when parts of it are not here?

Comment: Here ya go, it's just a basic Lerp function though.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing terrible things in your code. If you want to rasterize the line, the easiest way would be to use [DDA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)) (sometimes called Bresenham algorithm), which does not require floating point arithmetic and does not draw the same points several times.

Here's [another explanation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/line_generation_algorithm.htm) of the same concept.

And here's [yet another one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dda-line-generation-algorithm-computer-graphics/) with the C code included.

And once you read all the mentioned pages, treat the colour as one of the coordinates and apply the exactly same DDA algorithm for the colour as well.

Comment: I already used Bresenham in another line of code, but I'm supposed to have the Parametric code be the one with a gradient. Also, so you mean I can use the Bresenham algorithm itself to slowly go between colors?

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work*. also If you could say what's terrible in the code, I'd like to know what was wrong, so as to better my coding efficiency. *I basically took from the first link and replaced the dy with difference in the color. (seeing as longest is already either X or Y)

Comment: @NicholasHatcher "didn't work" is not very specific, unless you are able to share more details, I cannot tell you what to fix. start from replacing your floating point calculations with DDA, once done, you'll be able to do the same with the color calculations -- consider the color to be just another coordinate.

Comment: I did share more details hence the * used, I mentioned what I had done later in the comment.